# How to use custom views, e.g. setting drawable

Tags: android

I think I'm a bit confused about how to use custom views. I'm following along with slides from a talk given by Eric Burke from Square (from this year's anddevcon, slides here: http://www.andevcon.com/AndevCon_II/downloadpresentation.aspx?aid=Taming_Android__User_Experience_Lessons_from_Square_pdf.zip&sid=2).

His code, or at least the part he showed in the slides, went something like this:

```
public class EditablePhoto extends View {

    private Bitmap framedPhoto;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Drawable placeholder;

    public EditablePhoto(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                                       int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        //ensure view always square
        int min = Math.min(measuredHeight, measuredWidth);
        setMeasuredDimension(min, min);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(placeholder == null && image==null) return;

        if(framedPhoto == null) {
            createFramedPhoto(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(framedPhoto, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private void createFramedPhoto(int size) {

        Drawable imageDrawable = (image!=null)
                ? new BitmapDrawable(image) : placeholder;

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, 
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        RectF outerRect = new RectF(0, 0, size, size);
        float outerRadius = size / 18f;

        //Red rectangle

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(outerRect, outerRadius, outerRadius, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

         imageDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
        canvas.saveLayer(outerRect, paint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        imageDrawable.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

What I don't get is how to actually use this View now.... Where and when do you set the bitmaps, which are private fields in this class...?

Generally confused and would love some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

More than one year passed, but I hope this will help anyone who looking for the right answer. In my case, I putted this line of code

```
framedPhoto = output;
```

as the last one in createFramedPhoto() method. It works.
In the example, the author created a rounded rectangle as background then he draw the bitmap on it with XOR mode, so all pixel outside the rounded rectangle will be trim off.

Answer (score -1):

OnDraw() is the method where you will Draw your view on canvas. here too you can analyze onDraw() will fisrt call CreateFramePhoto then draw this Bitmap on canvas .

You can add this customView in layout Either from xml or in Java Class

**1) Through Xml :**

```
<EditablePhoto  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                ..........................
/>
```

dont forgate to add constructor EditablePhoto(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) for this case

**2) through Java class :**

```
EditablePhoto editablePhoto = new EditablePhoto(this);
addView(editablePhoto) // or do anthing you want with this
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this just really doesn't answer the question. All you did was explain what onDraw does in general. You didn't answer how to actually set the bitmaps/drawables.

Comment: Pass bitmap through constuctor .
 EditablePhoto(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, Bitmap bitmap) and save it inside class and use it

Comment: your query "What I don't get is how to actually use this View now.... " directed me in wrong way . will appreciate your downVote if you will describe your question correctly

Comment: In the example, if framedPhoto == null, then how does the createFramedPhoto take care of this...?